# Proper way to update server side props on Next.js page after client-side mutation?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Using Next.js, is there a "proper" method for updating the data on a page using `getServerSideProps` after a client-side mutation?

I'm familiar with this method:

```
  const handleRefresh = () => {
    router.replace(router.asPath);
  };
```

But wondering if there's a better way.

**Example**

I have a page that checks for a user session and fetches data belonging to that user in `getServerSideProps`--let's call the data "projects". Pieces of the user's project data is rendered by multiple client-side components on the page. One of these components allows the user to mutate some of the project data (a title, description) and save that back to the database.

Another component on the page renders a list of the project titles fetched from the server, so this means that the list needs to update to reflect the mutation performed by the user.

The current method I use for this is to send a `POST` request to an API route when the user mutates the data and then to call the `handleRefresh` function above if the update was successful, triggering a full reload of the page, thereby displaying the updated data in the components on the page.

Is this method the "proper" way to do this, or could my architecture here be improved such that I don't need the `handleRefresh` function call?

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you need is global state management.

You have one piece of the site that knows how that data is changing and it needs to share that new data with another part of the website. Global state management involves taking the state that needs to be shared between those components and putting it in a store accessible by both components.

Because react state will trigger those re-renders for you you don't have to worry about doing it yourself. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or the [react context API](https://react.dev/reference/react/hooks#context-hooks) can both be used for this but you should consider your use case when choosing a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you mean API calls would also be managed by global state? This is the only way I can see that working. A mutation occurs and the state management system fetches the new data and updates. I want the server side data to be the source of truth.